# How to read JSONP in ashx

Tags: c#, json, mootools, ashx

I'm trying to handle a JSONP request server side for a form submission ie.

```
var myJSONP = new Request.JSONP({
        url: 'http://mysite.../handlers/FormHandler.ashx',
        callbackKey: 'jsoncallback',
        data: {
            partTag: 'mtvo',
            iod: 'hlPrice',
            viewType: 'json',
            results: '100',
            query: 'ipod'
        },
        onRequest: function(url){
            // etc
        },
        onComplete: function(data){
            // etc
        }
    }).send();


 public class FormHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string json = ??
        JObject j = JObject.Parse(json);


        context.Response.ContentType = "text/json";
        context.Response.Write("Hello World");
    }
```

I'm not sure how to deserialize in the ashx ie. I use Json.Net but how to get from context
Do I have to use context.Request to retrieve values individually or can I decode directly from context?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure which JSONP you are using, but using MooTools `Request.JSON`, the data is delivered in `context.Request.Form`:

```
?context.Request.Form.ToString()
"partTag=mtvo&iod=hlPrice&viewType=json&results=100&query=ipod"
```

So you can access each of the form elements in code:

```
?context.Request.Form["partTag"]
"mtvo"
```

Based on this, I believe that you will have to assemble the object yourself using the form elements.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes, you need to use Context.Request to read the data from your client side.

BTW. if you can use RESTful web service instead of implement your own http handler, it will be much easier, RESTful web service which JSON   serialize  and deserialize is handled by the WCF framework.